# Make jQuery Slideshow fill the background of a web page

Tags: jquery

N.B. The links referenced in this post can be found [here](http://dgtgroup.co.uk/stack/links.html).

I am new to jquery and I am trying to use the CrossSlide plug-in (See Link 1), but I need the images to expand to fill the background of my webpage. It doesn't matter if they go out of proportion, as long as they fit.

The default settings for Crossslide  causes images to transition with a basic fade. Using the following CSS I can make the images fill the background:

```
#slideshow {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

See Link 2 for working example.

Cross Slide has an advance setting which allows images to transition with a panning effect.

I can get the panning effect working (see Link 3). However, if I try to use CSS to make the images fill the background, it stops working (see Link 4).

Could someone give me some pointers on how to achieve my goal.

(PS if the code in the examples seems a bit odd, its because I am using Drupal and just saved out these pages, so I would not have to have 3 different Drupal installs running. The actual Drupal site can be found in Link 5).

Comment: Would have been more useful to have the links in the question instead on an external site... :)

Comment: It only lets me post one link. :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are asking but try this:

### Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.slideHolder').crossSlide({
                sleep: 2,
                fade: 1
            }, [
  { src: 'Images/Chrysanthemum.jpg' },
  { src: 'Images/Penguins.jpg' },
  { src: 'Images/Tulips.jpg' }
]);

        });
</script>
```

### CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    .slideHolder
    {
        width:600px;
        height:300px;
    }
    .slideHolder img
    {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
</style>
```

### Answer

The key here is setting the `.slideHolder img` size so that the image stretches appropriately.

### EDIT

Crossslide is going to have some issues doing this as the image is required to be larger than the div that is being crossSlidified.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thanks!

I want the images to pan & then fade, so the jscript would have to be:
        $('#slideshow').crossSlide({
          speed: 45,
          fade: 1
        },

I also want the image to fill the background, so I think the CSS would have to be `width:100% height:100%`. But, when I change the CSS, the whole thing breaks. 

I've nearly achieved my goal with [JQuery Cycle][1]. But, I can only get that plug-in to Pan (and not fade when the images transition). 
[See my attempt][2]
  [1]: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ [2]: http://dgtgroup.co.uk/dgb/node/1

Answer (score 0):

Get the document.height and document.width.  and display a  inside the said W & H, and then display the image.  It should work out fine.

And on

```
.click(function() {

$('#').fadeIn();

});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help Jean.  I'm a little new to Java Script. Do you know of any resources that explain how I can get the W & H and how to use it to alter the image. Where would I put the code? Thanks!

Comment: Its more than just getting and setting the H & W.   You will have to custom code to get the desired output.

Comment: I think this is probably above my skill level for now. But thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: Nothing is above your level, you just have to put your head to it :), the idea is in front of you, implement a small test page, should work out fine